# Is there a Jenkins readFile plural equivalent? Like readFiles?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to utilize jenkins to read files into the output for multiple boxes. With the tools that I have used I am now successfully writing the input for the readFile into several files. I would like to know if there is a corresponding readFiles method that can be utilized in jenkins? Something like env.email_content = readFiles(files: {severalFiles}.ext)

I have looked at the jenkins documentation but didn't find any plural function.

Comment: describe please what you expect to see in variable email_content? content of both files?